# understanding effective length of a microcavity

Tags: optics, quantum-optics

to find the effective length of a microcavity you have to take into account the penetration outside of the cavity (as in quantum tunnelling)

> L<sub>effective</sub>=L<sub>cavity</sub>+L<sub>penetration</sub>

and mainly what's bothering me, is why take something that's escaping into account for essentially the distance between two mirrors? as far as the light that gets through is concerned its not a mirror. its not really acting as a cavity for that bit of light.

unless im not understanding this and it only escapes from the cavity a bit but gets pulled back.